# Return Partial View On Click Of Hyperlink

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, razor

Razor View:

```
@html.partial(Views/Shared/skill.cshtml)
<div class = "skillpartial" style="display:none">
@html.partial(Views/Shared/endorsers.cshtml)
</div>
```

Code generated from skill partial:

```
<div class="skill">
<span class="skillname"> Skills </span> <hr>       
<a class="skill_user_list" href="/?skill_id=1">Paperwork</a> <br>
<a class="skill_user_list" href="/?skill_id=2">Sales</a> <br>
<a class="skill_user_list" href="/?skill_id=3">IT</a> <br>
<a class="skill_user_list" href="/?skill_id=4">Communication</a> <br>
```

What I want is for endorsers partial view to be displayed on clicking on any of the above links without using any Ajax , JavaScript and Jquery.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you want to use ajax, js or jQuery?

Comment: Because I like to consider users who have their JavaScript disabled by default on browsers . Well the program I am developing is aimed at browsers without JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Pass the skill_id parameter through the controller to the view and use an if statement

Comment: Worked amazingly :)! , Thank you!